# How to send a multiple POST request in a single batch with different change sets id in SAP UI5?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to send multiple create request in a single batch.

Right now all request goes as a single change set id so if any records fails everything is rollback.

Can we send the multiple post request with different change sets id in a single batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of a [oData Batch](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/batch-processing/) Request is made up of an ordered series of `ChangeSets`.

In the Batch request body, **each retrieve request and ChangeSet is represented as a distinct MIME part.**

You should be using SAP gateway builder I hope. You have redefine/implement the interface procided by SAP ABAP gateway.

```
 /IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~CHANGESET_BEGIN.
/IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~CHANGESET_END
```

[Read more here in detail](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/17/implementing-batch-operations-in-odata/)

Within the body of the batch response is a response for each retrieve request and ChangeSet that was in the associated Batch request. The order of responses in the response body must match the order of requests in the Batch request.

*PS: If you still have trouble, you need to add your application, oData structure and interface methods redifined.*

Answer (score 0):

It worked after giving different value to `changeSetId`, each time when I call `createentry`.

Reference: https://answers.sap.com/questions/532601/how-to-send-a-multiple-post-request-in-a-single-ba.html